# Do puzzles like "write 120 using four 8" have a specific name?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers, puzzle-identification

Here on puzzling SE there is the category "calculation puzzle", but it's very broad. I'd like to know if somebody gave a specific name for such puzzles.

Comment: Are you looking for [tag:formation-of-numbers] tag?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis yes, thanks!

Comment: @JaapScherphuis (make this an *answer*?)